# BottomNavigationView with Fragment inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bottomnavigationview

I've got some problems understanding Fragments in Android.

The bottom navigation of my `MainActivity` has got three items: `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`, `FragmentC`.

`FragmentC` has got a button. When the user clicks that button, another `FragmentD` should display additional information.

- `FragmentD` should have an up-button in the toolbar. When the user clicks on that button, he gets back to `FragmentC`.
- When the user selects a different fragment from the navigation, `FragmentD` should disappear.

Inside the onClick of my button I've tried to use this

```
FragmentManager manager = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new FragmentD());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
```

with `nav_host_fragment` being the fragment container for the bottom navigation items of my MainActivity.

- Why doesn't `transaction.replace` replace `FragmentC` with `FragmentD`? When I press the button, `FragmentD` appears above `FragmentC` and has got a transparent background. `FragmentD` also does not get replaced by the other fragments when I select a different item from the bottom navigation. Is it because I'm using the `nav_host_fragment` container for `FragmentD`?
- How do I get the up-button?

Comment: Why are you trying to do a FragmentTransaction at all when you're using Navigation? Is there a reason you're not just [navigating to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)?

Comment: Thanks @ian, that has helped a lot.

In the Navigation xml file I've added FragmentD and an action for FragmentC with FragmentD as destination. In the button's onClick I now call Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.fragment_c_to_fragment_d);

The only thing that doesn't work is the up button in the toolbar. Do you know how I can make it work? It's there but it doesn't work.

Comment: Found it. I have to override onSupportNavigateUp: @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment).navigateUp()
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Navigation instead of FragmentTransaction.

In the Navigation xml file I've added FragmentD and an action for FragmentC with FragmentD as destination. In the button's onClick I now call `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.fragment_c_to_fragment_d);`

To make the button work, I had to override onSupportNavigateUp:

`@Override public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment).navigateUp() || 
        super.onSupportNavigateUp(); }`